# Enter ConversationHandler ignoring entry_points

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm using [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) wrapper to create NLP based chatbot and I want users to have an option how to use the bot:

- InlineKeyboardButton menus
- natural language conversation

For the first option I am having several ConversationHandlers defined, most of them are having entry_points defined as single CallbackQueryHandler:

```
location_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[
        CallbackQueryHandler(
            callback=nearest,
            pattern=NEAREST_CB
        )]
```

And for the second option I am using MessageHandler:

```
text_message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.command), call_model)
```

I wanna enter one of those ConversationHandlers whenever my model (`call_model` function) returns an appropriate tag, but have no idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> text_message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.command), call_model)
> ```
>
> I wanna enter one of those ConversationHandlers whenever my model (`call_model` function) returns an appropriate tag, but have no idea on how to do it.

`call_model` is your handler callback, though, right? The callback can't determine whether or not the handler is executed.

That is the job of the handler. So you should probably implement either a custom filter to use with `MessageHandler` or just a custom handler and put your NLP logic in there. Please see [this page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Advanced-Filters) for details on custom filters and [this page](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.handler.html) for the abstract `Handler` class that you'd need to implement for a custom handler.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`